# Are launch angles relative to observers?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Supposed we have someone on a moving platform which is at constant velocity. Lets say the person launches a mass at some speed relative to the platform an some angle with respect to the platform. Does the launch angle differs from say someone on the ground?

I know velocities are relatives, but I really can't see how the launch angle can be relative.

Answer (score 0):

The angle between the object being launched and the platform from which it is launched should remain the same to all observers unless they are moving at speeds comparable to the speed of light relative to the platform. At these speeds they will observe length contraction, the length along the axis which the objects are moving relative to each other will appear to be smaller. Because of this, the angle can easily change in different ways depending on the way that the objects are moving relative to each other.

When dealing with small speeds, the angles will look the same for all reference frames as the x component of the velocity of the platform (assuming the platform is moving on the x axis) will add to the velocity of the ball creating the same relative motion forward for the ball. At the same time the y axis stays the same relative to the platform, so the angle measured will be the same.